# Show the conformal transformation of the components of the Schouten tensor at the Spatial Infinity in an asymptotically flat spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, symmetry, curvature, asymptotics

In [Ashtekar & Hansen](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.523863), the authors discussed a unified treatment of null and spatial infinity in general relativity. In Section 5.D., they derived the relation (20). I failed to reproduce it.

Let me show some of my calculations.

Under the conformal transformation $\hat g'_{ab}=\omega^2\hat g_{ab}$, the Schouten tensor $\hat S_{ab}=\hat R_{ab}-\hat g_{ab}\hat R/6$ transforms in the following way,
\begin{equation}\label{eq-sp}
  \hat S'_{ab}=\hat S_{ab}-2\omega^{-1}\hat\nabla_a\hat\nabla_b\omega+4\omega^{-2}\hat\nabla_a\omega\hat\nabla_b\omega-\omega^{-2}\hat g_{ab}\hat{\nabla}_c\omega\hat\nabla^c\omega.
\end{equation}
So one has
\begin{equation}\label{eq-vsh}
  (\omega\Omega)^{1/2}\hat S'_{ab}=\omega^{1/2}(\Omega^{1/2}\hat S_{ab})-\Omega^{1/2}  (2\omega^{-1/2}\hat\nabla_a\hat\nabla_b\omega-4\omega^{-3/2}\hat\nabla_a\omega\hat\nabla_b\omega+\omega^{-3/2}\hat g_{ab}\hat{\nabla}_c\omega\hat\nabla^c\omega).
\end{equation}

Now, one can take the limit to get

$$\hat{\mathbb{S}}'_{ab}=\hat{\mathbb S}_{ab}-\lim_{\rightarrow i^0}\Big[\Omega^{1/2}  (2\omega^{-1/2}\hat\nabla_a\hat\nabla_b\omega-4\omega^{-3/2}\hat\nabla_a\omega\hat\nabla_b\omega+\omega^{-3/2}\hat g_{ab}\hat{\nabla}_c\omega\hat\nabla^c\omega)\Big].$$

Here, I define 
$$\hat{\mathbb S}_{ab}=\lim_{\rightarrow i^0}\Omega^{1/2}\hat S_{ab}.$$

So it seems that indeed, $\hat{\mathbb S}_{ab}$ is not conformally invariant. But how to obtain (20)?